# Reactj.NET on Azure web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a website using reactjs.net which is working fine on my local IIS.

The web site is using asp.net MVC 4.6.1 C#, and uses Umbraco 7.6.4 for the CMS but this i think is unrelated.

When we upload the web site to an Azure web app, the initial server side JavaScript executes, but after that no future react js runs.

I've added `console.log` to the beginning of the methods inside the react .js files and when on local they're appearing fine, when on the web app nothing is outputted.

Does anyone know of this issue?

Comment: Do you have a glance at [Reactjs.net offical document](https://reactjs.net/guides/azure.html)? `From version 2.2 onwards ReactJS.NET works out of the box in Azure using the V8 JavaScript engine. Versions prior to 2.2.0 will fall back to using MSIE JavaScript engine and you may experience JavaScript errors during server-side rendering that you aren't experiencing locally.` I also find a related [blog](http://www.samulihaverinen.com/web-development/dotnet/2016/01/19/how-to-run-clearscript-v8-javascript-engine-in-azure/). Hope it is useful.

Comment: @TomSun, if you add this as an answer i'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Ok, I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may get the answer from the Reactjs.net [offical document](https://reactjs.net/guides/azure.html). I also find a related blog, more details please refer to [it](http://www.samulihaverinen.com/web-development/dotnet/2016/01/19/how-to-run-clearscript-v8-javascript-engine-in-azure/).

> From version 2.2 onwards ReactJS.NET works out of the box in Azure using the V8 JavaScript engine. Versions prior to 2.2.0 will fall back to using MSIE JavaScript engine and you may experience JavaScript errors during server-side rendering that you aren't experiencing locally.